# Blackberry localstorage

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am developing a hybrid(phonegap and webworks) Blackberry application.I am using localstroage to save variable data.Please tell me how we can view the variable data and where blackberry application is stroing that data in the devie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic demo:

```
//Insert/Update 
window.localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar");       //foo = bar

//Read
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("foo");  //bar

//Remove
window.localStorage.removeItem("foo");  //foo = undefined

//Remove all
window.localStorage.clear();  //length = 0
```

Here is an example I wrote that shows how to use the localStorage API on BlackBerry:
http://blackberry.github.io/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/html5/storage.html

You can re-use this code in either a browser-based web page, a PhoneGap application or a WebWorks application.